# OpenSeaMap data and their attributation

Tags: openseamap

I am downloading OpenSeaMap data using the overpass api. However, using ["seamark:type"] is not downloading all the data shown in the TSM ([https://tiles.openseamap.org/seamark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://tiles.openseamap.org/seamark/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)) and downloading data without the seamark type I am drowning in more or less unclassified data.

Hence I am very interested in information on how data are filtered in the OpenSeaMap project to achieve the data shown on OpenSeaMap.org!
It is not only the knowledge what data goes in, but also based on what attributes the symbolization / style is set. For example, most of the buoy are within the group of 'unknown_point', and looking at the attributes, I cannot find an indicator why some of the points are vertex points of restricted area polygons, and others are buoys.

Looking forward to some insights!

---

ps: I never managed to get into the OpenSeaMap forum, so if any of the good people from this forum are reading here: please make it happen that any credentials work, it's only an email and a password...

Comment: Since this is open data I think a place to ask this is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PolyGeo Done, though I wonder what the chances are to get an answer in a beta-group. Therefor, I would appreciate if we can keep the posting here.